# Chrome grey box appearing (border-bottom-color, outline-color, color?)

Tags: css, google-chrome, colors

I have an odd light grey, what I think is a background box rendered by Chrome. I cannot seem to be able to override it with a reset nor additional CSS values that would negate the box.

Screenshot:

[image]

```
color: rgb(127, 127, 127);
display: block;
font-family: Georgia;
font-size: 16px;
height: 300.59375px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
outline-color: rgb(127, 127, 127);
```

This seem to be the source of the problem, either the color value or the outline value, but I can't seem to override this... Using current HTML5reset

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried: `border-style: none;` ?